# Python Socket host returning EOF while waiting for input to send

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm currently trying to make a messaging application that allows a Client and Host to communicate with each other using user input. The general idea is to have the host user input a name and the client should input a name and ip address and the two users should be able to communicate.

Host code:

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class Host:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DispName = input("What should your Display Name be? ")
        self.address = None
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 7735))
        self.s.listen(5)
        print(f"Your IP address is {socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())}")
        self.initial_message = "Connection Success"

    def SendData(self):
        while True:
            ClientSocket, self.address = self.s.accept()
            print(f"Connection received from {self.address}, happy chatting!")
            ClientSocket.send(bytes(f"{self.DispName}> {self.initial_message}", "utf-8"))
            while True:
                message = input(f"{self.DispName}> ")
                ClientSocket.send(bytes(f"{self.DispName}> {message}", "utf-8"))

    def RecvData(self):
        while True:
            client_socket, client_address = self.s.accept()
            print(f"Connection received from {client_address}, ready to receive messages")
            while True:
                msg = client_socket.recv(1024)
                if not msg:
                    break
                print(msg.decode("utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    H = Host()
    q = Queue()
    SendProcess = Process(target=H.SendData)
    RecvProcess = Process(target=H.RecvData)

    SendProcess.start()
    RecvProcess.start()
    SendProcess.join()
    RecvProcess.join()
```

Host Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cohen\Code\Python\Heavy Encryption Messaging\Main\Connecting Methods\Host.py", line 21, in SendData
    message = input(f"{self.DispName}> ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Client Code:

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DispName = input("What should your Display Name be? ")
        self.address = None
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host_ip = input("What is the IP address of your Host? ")
        self.s.connect((host_ip, 7735))
        print(f"Connected to {host_ip}, happy chatting!")
        self.Init_Msg = "Connection Successful"

    def SendData(self):
        self.s.send(bytes(f"{self.DispName}> {self.Init_Msg}", "utf-8"))
        while True:
            message = input(f"{self.DispName}> ")
            self.s.send(bytes(f"{self.DispName}> {message}", "utf-8"))

    def RecvData(self):
        while True:
            msg = self.s.recv(1024)
            print(msg.decode("utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    C = Client()
    SendProcess = Process(target=C.SendData)
    RecvProcess = Process(target=C.RecvData)

    SendProcess.start()
    RecvProcess.start()
    SendProcess.join()
    RecvProcess.join()
```

Client Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cohen\Code\Python\Heavy Encryption Messaging\Main\Connecting Methods\Client.py", line 18, in SendData
    message = input(f"{self.DispName}> ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cohen\Code\Python\Heavy Encryption Messaging\Main\Connecting Methods\Client.py", line 23, in RecvData
    msg = self.s.recv(1024)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: So the peer closed the connection. So handle it, like you did in the server. Nothing is forever.

Comment: You do a single connect in the client side before you fork into one process for sending and one for receiving. On the server side you instead have two accepts - one in the sending and one in the receiving part. This does not match - one connect vs. two accept.  And in general I find this pretty strange design with having separate processing for sending and receiving (contrary for example to using multiple threads), No idea where you got this from.